Post command not working in C# app, but works fine with postman
I have a created a server code which accepts file through post command.
Server side code:
   app.MapPost("/upload2", async (IFormFile file) =>
   {
    List<string> validextensions = new List<string>() { ".xlsx" };
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
    if (!validextensions.Contains(extension))
    {
        return $"Extention is not valid({string.Join(",", validextensions)})";
    }
    string filename = "File1" + extension;
    string path = @"D:/";
    using FileStream stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(path, filename), FileMode.Create);
    file.CopyToAsync(stream);

    return filename;
   });

   app.MapGet("/GetToken", async (HttpContext context, IAntiforgery antiforgery) =>
   {
    // Generate the antiforgery token
    var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
    var requestToken = tokens.RequestToken;

    // Include the token in the response
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    await context.Response.WriteAsync(requestToken);
   });

I believe this code is ok because it works fine in postman. However, I failed sending file through C#!
Client code:
public async Task SendExcelFileToServer(string filepath, string filename, string InnerAddress)
{
    try
    {
        // Create an instance of HttpClient
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            // Set the request URI
            string requestUri = ServerAddressTextBox.Text.Trim() + InnerAddress;

            // Create multipart form data content
            using (var form = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                string antiforgeryToken, cookie;
                (antiforgeryToken, cookie) = await GetAntiforgeryToken();

                // Add file part
                using (var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(filepath)))
                {
                    //form.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
                    //form.Add(fileContent, "file", filename);

                    // This Is obligatory inn .net8! :)
                    // Add the RequestVerificationToken header

                    form.Headers.Add("RequestVerificationToken", "CfDJ8IobTqaCf0xCi3hgie2deVpx3DCZeGmVD28L6YAsM51Szh1AF0afHexqh7O768rwdYqOqLx8ph3yM86l7bg_phwtnHFspWVdFBtKScLlooFE_10wA6HidiiMZT6TbqZsR5Q1l6C7qJ9Zcuj_1bhxt10");

                    // Add the cookie header
                    form.Headers.Add("Cookie", ".AspNetCore.Antiforgery.p8-WnM9DThg=CfDJ8IobTqaCf0xCi3hgie2deVrgEG5nQyY-SHCgXvPCDh8LFzaqG7fOX41qgeGCXUcjPKgAPvPRqEUgYhzhHLTfcnClNq5rmQIZ-CkycC_V0vzBYhSgXdCVnL_9_ftvHXhYl7S3RR575hPwsAUvKg9D8kQ");
                    //form.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/octet-stream");
                    //httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "*/*");

                    //httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
                    //httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");

                    // Send post request
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, form);

                    // Check response
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Try sending data again and check your connection!");
    }
}

I added
RequestVerificationToken to my postman post command manually. Also, I added it to my post command in C#. Although Postman command is successful, C# post command does not work.
As you can see based on my comments in client code, I have tried so many options. But they all failed.
response of server to the client in c#:
    {StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, 
    Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
    {
        Connection: close
        Transfer-Encoding: chunked
        Date: Wed, 08 May 2024 07:39:44 GMT
        Server: Kestrel
        Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
    }}


That server code doesn't seem to expect multipartformdata. Why is your client sending that?

You said However, I failed sending file through C#!. Can you pls share the error message or exception?

Hi @Kian Farooghi, I shared the answer which could achieve your requirement, pls check.

First your client sample code didn't add fileContent in form but only add Headers in form, so you will send a empty form to server and get error of course. (or you can just remove comment)
form.Add(fileContent, "file", filename);

And you can try to add Headers in fileContent instead of form. If it not works then here is a worked upload file sample by WebApplication and HttpClient.
Server Code
var app = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args).Build();
app.MapPost("/upload2", (HttpContext ctx) =>
{
    return ctx.Request.Form.Files.First().FileName;
});
app.Run();

Client Code
var filePath = "./test.xlsx";
var fileName = "test.xlsx";
var requestUri = "http://localhost:5000/upload2";
using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
using var form = new MultipartFormDataContent {
    {
        new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath)), "file", fileName
    }
};
Console.WriteLine(httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, form).Result);


Just share the working code in my side:
  using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        // Set the request URI
        string requestUri = "https://localhost:xxx/upload2";
        HttpResponseMessage tokenResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:xxx/GetToken");
        tokenResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        //get the token
        string token = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        // Create multipart form data content
        using (var form = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            using (var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath)))
            {
                form.Add(fileContent, "file", filename); 
                form.Headers.Add("RequestVerificationToken", token);
                HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, form);

                // Check response
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            }
        }
    }

Be sure register the service in the server side Program.cs file:
builder.Services.AddAntiforgery();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAntiforgery();
app.MapPost("/upload2", async (IFormFile file) =>
{
    //...
});
app.MapGet("/GetToken", async (HttpContext context, IAntiforgery antiforgery) =>
{
    //...
});

